How to use differential-entropy as pre-processing?
I am currently working on implementing the model EEG_DMNet. For pre-processing it calls for using differential entropy like
$$
h(X) = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) \log p(x) \, dx
$$
Assuming the Data I am using is gaussian-distributed the formula can be simplified to
$$
h(X) = \frac{1}{2} \log(2\pi e \sigma^2)
$$
My problem is, that I do not understand what "using differential entropy" means. The shape of the input x is $$
x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times C} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times T}
$$
and the output shape should be the same. When trying to add a pre-processing layer in keras, the output shape is not correct.
def call(self, inputs):
     variance = tf.math.reduce_variance(inputs, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
     differential_entropy = 0.5 * tf.math.log(2 * np.pi * np.e * variance)
     return differential_entropy


I'm as confused as you: DE is a statistic of a distribution... furthermore, the paper that they cite near the equation has nothing to do with DE... but it's not surprising checking the journal it's published on

@Alberto That is not the answer I hoped for, but at least I feel a bit less stupid now

Another very suspicious thing is that in 4.3.1 they show the difference between using it and not... usually a preprocessing does not cause such a large difference, except if the data is in an extremely bad scale (something like with entries in [-100, 100])

@Alberto That one also baffled me, but I thought then this preproccesing must be really effective. What is weird that there are some more papers talking about using Differential Entropy as pre-processing

So, one thing might be to normalize X so that it maximizes entropy. in other words $argmax_{f} H(f(x))$. This corresponds to find a kernel function $f$ that maps the CDF of your distribution $p(x)$ to a uniform distribution. To do so, you should estimate the CDF of every feature indipendently, and then find the correct $f$ (see for example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling where it is done to do sampling instead of normalization)... usually, this is done in a discrete setting, thus dicretizing the data, and then "reweighting the bin"

I'm leaving this answer since I think it's the MLE answer, though it might be wrong, since in the paper they leave a loooot of room for imagination.
To do so, you need to compute the quantiles of the distribution of your features, and replace the features by their corresponding quantiles. There are many ways to do so, one is to use Kernel Density Estimation as an estimate of $p(x)$, and then use that to compute quantiles. (Each feature is considered indipendently)

In poor words, you want the information from the features to be maximized. Thus, you want maximal entropy. Such maximal entropy is obtained when you deal with a uniform distribution.
However, this is not quite the way of reading it, in my opinion. Instead, I'd suggest you to read it as a way to be "more sensitive to values that appear frequently".
Take a $Beta(10,10)$ distribution:

most of the samples will be near $0.5$ $\rightarrow$ therefore, you are "wasting the values near 0 and 1".
What you could do, is to drop everything that is not in $[0.25,0.75]$ $\rightarrow$ remove the extrema, that are very unlikely and only consider the center part
this would cause loss of information, but the information is "spread more uniformly" (aka, it looks more like a uniform distribution)
instead, you can consider the quantiles of the distribution, that instead is a invertible transformation, so no information is lost, but you are more uniformly spreading the information across the $[0,1]$ range

Now, I believe in the "one picture is worth 1000 words", so here's my picture:

In blue you have the PDF (not normalized) of a $Beta(10,10)$, in orange the CDF of it. What you can see from the green lines, is that values between $[0.4, 0.6]$ are "amplified" to almost $[0.2, 0.8]$, therefore the network is "less sensitive" to changes in that range, which is (by the definition of the PDF) the most likely

First of all thank you so much for your effort.  I would have never thought about a solution like that. After reading different papers that use the same technique like this or this I believe they went for a simpler approach. I think they just windowed the data and calculated differential entropy for each window. The papers I mentioned do that for different frequency bands, but as the shape after differential entropy should be (4,25) I dont think they did that as the shape would be three dimensional.

@SebastianKrafft that window approach is an approximation of the approach i’ve described… and tbh, i think is also what RobustScaler of sklearn is doing

I think I didnt read your answer thorough enough the first time. Your approach would be to scale the data to form a more uniform pdf and therefore maximise the DE of the data. This way no information would be lost. I will for sure try this out and see how it works. I believe though, that in the original paper they took f.e. a 2 second window, calculated DE for that window and continued with that value, so that effectively information is lost. To me that's easier to read from the formula they use, even though they did not mention any window length. Thanks again, I learned a lot from your answer

@SebastianKrafft yup don’t worry, maybe i’ve not explained myself in the best way… but yes, the approach i’ve described wants to distribute uniformly the values, to have maximal DE. Other words, if you take a specific feature, and you do an histogram of it with the values of it in the whole dataset, you should see some weird distribution (marginal distribution of that feature)… after what i described, if you check the histogram you should see a uniform distribution (or almost)
